# Download Web Page with Resources using Java

Tags: java, web-crawler

Is there any any api available that capture whole java page just like browser save as option does?

Answer (score 0):

I think emulating a browser in your case might be a easy solution (though a bit heavyweight). Look into [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html).

Answer (score 0):

you can try and have a look at Lobo : http://lobobrowser.org/java-browser.jsp which is a web-based Java browser. They might provide a way for you to just download a whole page with the resources in a directory.
Another way could be to use something like Selenium and start a Firefox instance in your java app after you recorded a macro for going to File -> Save As ... etc.